# How to select all underlined text in a paragraph

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to create a google apps script that will format certain parts of a paragraph. For example, text that is underlined will become bolded/italicized as well.

One docs add-on I have tried has a similar feature: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WIkp.jpg (this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve)

**How can I write a function that will select a certain type of text and format it?**

**I managed to write a script that iterates through every single letter in a paragraph and checks if it's underlined, but it becomes extremely slow as the paragraph gets longer, so I'm looking for a faster solution.

```js
function textUnderline() {
  var selectedText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();  
  if(selectedText) {
    var elements = selectedText.getRangeElements();
    for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
      var element = elements[index];
      if(element.getElement().editAsText) {        
        var text = element.getElement().editAsText();
        var textLength = text.getText().length;        
        //For every single character, check if it's underlined and then format it
        for (var i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {        
          if(text.isUnderline(i)) {          
            text.setBold(i, i, true);
            text.setBackgroundColor(i,i,'#ffff00');               
          } else {            
            text.setFontSize(i, i, 8);             
          } 
        }   
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the script that iterates through each letter to see if it's underlined?

Comment: Is that necessary? I simply want to know how to select specific text from a paragraph (just like the imgur gif I linked)

Comment: So you want what you want and your not interested in sharing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on? If you show what you tried, more people will be willing to help you.

Comment: I added the code to the post. Let me repeat that I'm not trying to use or edit my current code (which iterates through every character and takes extremely long for large paragraphs). I'm trying to understand how to program a function that does what is shown in the gif I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use getTextAttributeIndices:

There is no need to check each character in the selection. You can use [getTextAttributeIndices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getTextAttributeIndices()) to get the indices in which the text formatting changes. This method:

> Retrieves the set of text indices that correspond to the start of distinct text formatting runs.

You just need to iterate through these indices (that is, check the indices in which text formatting changes), which are a small fraction of all character indices. This will greatly increase efficiency.

#### Code sample:

```js
function textUnderline() {
  var selectedText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();  
  if(selectedText) {
    var elements = selectedText.getRangeElements();
    for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
      var element = elements[index];
      if(element.getElement().editAsText) {        
        var text = element.getElement().editAsText();
        var textRunIndices = text.getTextAttributeIndices();
        var textLength = text.getText().length;
        for (let i = 0; i < textRunIndices.length; i++) {
          const startOffset = textRunIndices[i];
          const endOffset = i + 1 < textRunIndices.length ? textRunIndices[i + 1] - 1 : textLength - 1;
          if (text.isUnderline(textRunIndices[i])) {
            text.setBold(startOffset, endOffset, true);
            text.setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffset,'#ffff00');  
          } else {
            text.setFontSize(startOffset, endOffset, 8);
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getTextAttributeIndices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getTextAttributeIndices())

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example shown in the animated gif, it seems your procedure needs to

- handle a selection
- set properties if the selected region is of some format (e.g. underlined)
- set properties if the selected region is NOT of some format (e.g. not underlined)
- finish as fast as possible

and your example code achieves all these goals expect the last one.

The problem is that you are calling the `text.set...()` functions at each index position.  Each call is synchronous and blocks the code until the document is updated, thus your run time grows linearly with each character in the selection.

My suggestion is to build up a collection of subranges from the selection range and then for each subrange use `text.set...(subrange.start, subrange.end)` to apply the formatting.  Now the run time will be dependent on chunks of characters, rather than single characters.  i.e., you will only update when the formatting switches back and forth from, in your example, underlined to not underlined.

Here is some example code that implements this subrange idea.  I separated the specific predicate function (`text.isUnderline`) and specific formatting effects into their own functions so as to separate the general idea from the specific implementation.

```js
// run this function with selection
function transformUnderlinedToBoldAndYellow() {
  transformSelection("isUnderline", boldYellowOrSmall);
}

function transformSelection(stylePredicateKey, stylingFunction) {
  const selectedText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (!selectedText) return;
  const getStyledSubRanges = makeStyledSubRangeReducer(stylePredicateKey);
  selectedText.getRangeElements()
    .reduce(getStyledSubRanges, [])
    .forEach(stylingFunction);
}

function makeStyledSubRangeReducer(stylePredicateKey) {
  return function(ranges, rangeElement) {
    const {text, start, end} = unwrapRangeElement(rangeElement);
    if (start >= end) return ranges; // filter out empty selections
    const range = {
      text, start, end,
      styled: [], notStyled: [] // we will extend our range with subranges
    };
    const getKey = (isStyled) => isStyled ? "styled" : "notStyled";
    let currentKey = getKey(text[stylePredicateKey](start));
    range[currentKey].unshift({start: start});
    for (let index = start + 1; index <= end; ++index) {
      const isStyled = text[stylePredicateKey](index);
      if (getKey(isStyled) !== currentKey) { // we are switching styles
        range[currentKey][0].end = index - 1; // note end of this style
        currentKey = getKey(isStyled);
        range[currentKey].unshift({start: index}); // start new style range
      }
    }
    ranges.push(range);
    return ranges;
  }
}

// a helper function to unwrap a range selection, deals with isPartial,
// maps RangeElement => {text, start, end}
function unwrapRangeElement(rangeElement) {
  const isPartial = rangeElement.isPartial();
  const text = rangeElement.getElement().asText();
  return {
    text: text,
    start: isPartial
      ? rangeElement.getStartOffset()
      : 0,
    end: isPartial
      ? rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive()
      : text.getText().length - 1
  };
}

// apply specific formatting to satisfy the example
function boldYellowOrSmall(range) {
  const {text, start, end, styled, notStyled} = range;
  styled.forEach(function setTextBoldAndYellow(range) {
    text.setBold(range.start, range.end || end, true);
    text.setBackgroundColor(range.start, range.end || end, '#ffff00');
  });
   notStyled.forEach(function setTextSmall(range) {
    text.setFontSize(range.start, range.end || end, 8);
  });
}
```